# Page title not detected in WAVE

Tags: html, accessibility

When scanning a particular web page, the WAVE audit tool reports it has no page title even though it clearly does. Is there some other content-related criteria that could cause a page title to fail a WAVE scan?

Comment: What's the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed now. Turns out there were other empty title tags deeper in the page body. I notified the WAVE folks and they're going to make a correction to the tool. Having multiple title tags is not allowed, but it shouldn't have affected the recognition of the primary title tag.

Comment: did the empty `<title>` tags cause the valid title to be flagged?

Comment: Yes. The developer at WAVE said this shouldn't happen, so they're going to make a fix.